# Fastest approach to using raw sockets in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, winsock

I am trying to improve the performance of .NET 5 based network code to improve the throughput. I have been using the standard .NET Sockets implementation - but have hit something of a brick wall when it comes to throughput at around 200Mbps (1kb packets). I have tried both variants of async pattern (Begin... and SendToAsync...) and using a dedicated thread using synchronous operations - but can't improve performance any further. The overall CPU load is less than 50% on sender and receiver - and the machines are connected at 1Gbps.

I have also tried using Pcap.Net and even a Windows Packet Filter driver (http://ntkernel.com) to plug into NDIS below the sockets layer.

Reading around suggests that perhaps Registered I/O would be a good approach, but in my case I need to use SocketType.Raw (since I need to handle GRE, SCTP and various other protocols other than UDP and TCP). It appears that the Registered I/O API does not support raw (IP-level) sockets (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mswsock/nc-mswsock-lpfn_riocreaterequestqueue)

The profiler suggests that the time is spent within WSASendTo - and the .NET Socket class introduces little additional overhead. This suggests that even moving from C# to C++ using Winsock directly is unlikely to help much. I would rather steer clear of getting into Kernel development.

Is there anything similar to Registered I/O which would work with raw sockets? It seems strange that Registered I/O should support UDP but not IP directly. Any other ideas how I can resolve this bottleneck? Are there any inefficiencies inherent in Winsock relating to raw sockets (as opposed to UDP and TCP)?

As requested - added a simple example to send 1Kb dummy GRE packets as fast as possible. This results in about 270Mbps throughput and about 30% CPU evenly across all cores. Performance is broadly the same using localhost - which I think rules-out the network card as being the bottleneck.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace RawSender
{
    class Program
    {
        private static readonly ConcurrentBag<SocketAsyncEventArgs> ArgsPool = new ConcurrentBag<SocketAsyncEventArgs>();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var Destination = IPAddress.Parse(args[0]);

            // Create pool of SocketAsyncEventArgs for the async operations

            for (int Index=0;Index<10_000;Index++)
            {
                var Args = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
                Args.SetBuffer(new byte[1000]);
                Args.Completed += OnComplete;
                Args.RemoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(Destination, 0);
                ArgsPool.Add(Args);
            }

            // Send 1 million dummy 1kb packets using IP protocol 47 (GRE)
            
            var Socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, (ProtocolType)47);
            for(int Scan=0;Scan<1_000_000;Scan++)
            {
                if (!ArgsPool.TryTake(out SocketAsyncEventArgs Args)) throw new Exception("Args pool empty");
                if (!Socket.SendToAsync(Args))
                {
                    OnComplete(null, Args);
                }
            }
        }

        private static void OnComplete(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
        {
            ArgsPool.Add(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We'll need a [mcve].

Comment: People have been writing high-performance socket code long before RIO was a thing.  Using RIO just makes it a bit more efficient by reducing some of the overhead of transitioning between user-mode and kernel-mode.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Not sure what example I can provide - since I'm asking about the availability of an API similar to RIO which supports raw sockets. However, I've added a very simply example which demonstrates the limited throughput using standard async sockets.

Comment: Would TPL DataFlow be beneficial here?

Comment: I'm already using TPL within the platform, but I don't know of any way to send raw packets aside from through the standard Sockets implementation - which isn't providing the performance required.

Answer (score 2):

Playing around with your code it seems you're limited by the amount of packet overhead being sent. With your code as written I'm getting a 246MB/s throughput, and when I increase the buffer size to 10000 (ie 10 times larger than yours) I'm getting 2346MB/s (ie 10 times larger again).

So much like any other kind of socket programming, group your socket messages together better, and don't say you can't if you have *millions of these things* being sent every second.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm limited by (i) the MTU of the network path (1500 bytes including headers), and (ii) the specification of the protocol being used - so I can't bundle bytes into arbitrarily large packets. I suspect, as you say, that the issue is the per packet processing overhead (perhaps user/kernel transitions) - which is why I was interested in Registered I/O which does support millions of packets per send (see http://video.ch9.ms/build/2011/slides/SAC-593T_Briggs.pptx) but not raw sockets.

Comment: Not sure I understand point ii. Are you saying you can't increase your buffer size and put multiple application layer messages into the same buffer?

Comment: These are raw IP packets (not UDP or TCP). If I create a large buffer (and don't set the DF flag), then the messages will be fragmented and the framing will be lost. If I do set the DF flag, then if I supply more than an MTU-worth of data, it will fail with a MessageSize error.

Comment: @MikeBrom, depending on your network setup, and specifically if you control all the routers along the way, you can increase the MTU. The 1500 MTU isn't a maximum, it's just a legacy value that works "well enough" now.

Comment: Unfortunately the network involved is the Internet - not much chance of me changing the MTU