# C# Mechanism for setting or reading custom TCP options

Tags: c#, sockets

Is there a mechanism in C# with either `TcpClient` or `Socket` to directly set (on the client side) kinds, lengths, and values in the TCP options sent on the `SYN` packet, and then, the ability to read the kinds, lengths, and values when the `SYN` is received server-side using `TcpListener`?

The use case is to automatically-detect client capabilities when a TCP connection is requesting connection establishment with a server without relying on the exchange of TCP payload data, i.e. if the presence of a TCP option exists, then the server side can assume that the client is capable of a certain capability.  Specifically, looking for the ability to set custom options and not those pre-defined, and preferably, one that works across multiple frameworks and operating systems.

Comment: So you want `RAW` sockets? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65693543/fastest-approach-to-using-raw-sockets-in-net

Comment: c# is managed and doesn't let you read all the parameters in the TCP header.  You can use ImportDll with the windows library.  See : https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/ws2_32/socket.html?diff=y&force_isolation=true

Comment: Hi @Dai not raw sockets necessarily, I don't want to build my own transport.  I just want the ability to read/write to TCP options.